# Не могу собрать QMYSQL под Windows

Tags: mysql, qt, qmake

Знаю, что тема очень избитая, но у меня не получается собрать драйвер MySQL для Qt 5.8 (MinGW). Гуглил хорошо, пробовал массу вариантов.

1. Скачал MySQL Connector C x86 с официального сайта
2. Скачал Qt 5.8 MinGW32, в установке отметил Sources

Глобальные переменные окружения, если что

> C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0mingw\5.8\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>where
>   qmake C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0mingw\5.8\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe
>
> C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0mingw\5.8\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>where
>   mingw32-make C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0mingw\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe

Установил MySQL Connector в C:\Qt\Mysql. Проблем с кириллицей/пробелами не должно быть.

3. Выполнил команды:

> C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0mingw\5.8\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>qmake
>   "INCLUDEPATH+=C:\Qt\MySQL\include"
>   "LIBS+=C:\Qt\MySQL\lib\libmysql.lib" mysql.pro

Далее выполнил команду

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0mingw\5.8\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>mingw32-make
mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release all
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Qt/Qt5.8.0mingw/5.8/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql'
...
g++ -Wl,-s -shared -Wl,-subsystem,windows -Wl,--out-implib,C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0mingw\5.8\Src\qtbase\plugins\sqldrivers\libqsqlmysql.a -o ..\..\..\..\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlmysql.dll .obj/release/qsql_mysql.o .obj/release/main.o .obj/release/moc_qsql_mysql_p.o  -LC:\utils\my_sql\my_sql\lib -LC:\utils\postgresql\pgsql\lib C:\Qt\MySQL\lib\libmysql.lib -LC:\Qt\Qt5.8.0mingw\5.8\mingw53_32\lib C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0mingw\5.8\mingw53_32\lib\libQt5Sql.a C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0mingw\5.8\mingw53_32\lib\libQt5Core.a -llibmysql .obj\release\qsqlmysql_resource_res.o
C:/Qt/Qt5.8.0mingw/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibmysql
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.Release:65: recipe for target '..\..\..\..\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlmysql.dll' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [..\..\..\..\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlmysql.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/Qt5.8.0mingw/5.8/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql'
Makefile:38: recipe for target 'release-all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [release-all] Error 2
```

cannot find -llibmysql
Элементарная вроде ошибка, много решений в гугле, но никак не могу решить проблему. Что я не так делаю?

**UPD** Либы вроде собрал. Только вот странная проблема. Не хочу плодить тему по такому пустяку(хотя для меня это не пустяк).

Если создавать подключение так:

```
QSqlDatabase pDB = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
pDB.setHostName("sql11.freemysqlhosting.net");
pDB.setDatabaseName("sql11177506");
pDB.setPort(3306);
pDB.setUserName("sql11177506");
pDB.setPassword("ITIziMsIWx");
qDebug() << pDB.open() << pDB.lastError().text();
```

То как-бы работает. 
А если через указатель:

```
QSqlDatabase *pDB = new QSqlDatabase;

pDB->addDatabase("QMYSQL");
pDB->setHostName("sql11.freemysqlhosting.net");
pDB->setDatabaseName("sql11177506");
pDB->setPort(3306);
pDB->setUserName("sql11177506");
pDB->setPassword("ITIziMsIWx");
qDebug() << pDB->open() << pDB->lastError().text();
```

То пишет `Driver not loaded Driver not loaded`
Почему так не работает?

Comment: На всякий спрошу: у вас win32 ?

Comment: 64. Но ведь нету разницы, когда компилятор 32 и либы. Так же, да?

Comment: По моему есть разница. Если у вас 64 то и программы надо устанавливать в этих битах .

Comment: Мне нужно , чтобы работало с mingw32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0mingw\5.8\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=C:\Qt\MySQL\include" "LIBS+=-LC:\Qt\MySQL\lib" mysql.pro
```

По поводу второй проблемы, попробуйте так:

```
QSqlDatabase *pDB = new QSqlDatabase;

*pDB = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
pDB->setHostName("sql11.freemysqlhosting.net");
pDB->setDatabaseName("sql11177506");
pDB->setPort(3306);
pDB->setUserName("sql11177506");
pDB->setPassword("ITIziMsIWx");
```

Comment: Кстати, уже собрал. Как раз таким способом

Comment: Но есть одна проблема. Я добавлю в шапку сейчас

Comment: @Desmond Fox обновил ответ

Comment: заработало(по крайней мере оно делает вид, что работает)! Спасибо огромное, я уже второй день сижу с этой проблемой, а проблема была в одной строчке. Я аж подгорел с такого. Спасибо ещё раз!